# How to enable USB OTG in Walton Primo F4?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-on-the-go

I have a Walton Primo F4, running Android 4.2.2. How can I enable USB OTG in my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head into settings, about device, then tap the build number 7 times. From there, head back and you will see a menu called ***developer options***. Tap it,  and tap enable USB debugging. Accept the warning,  and you are done.

Comment: What does USB debugging have anything to do with USB OTG?

Comment: @Firelord Honestly?  No idea.  A small glitch to my device involves me randomly needing USB debugging for OTG,  so.....

Comment: @Firelord Besides, it seems to have worked...